# Google Drive API grant access to another/multiple Apps

Tags: google-drive-api

Currently, we have a mobile App that is storing data into a Google Drive folder using the scope

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
```

> View and manage Google Drive files and folders that you have opened or created with this app

Now we are planning to add a web app as well. The problem is, that the web app cannot access files uploaded by the mobile app and vice versa.

So is there a way to tell the Google Drive API that those two apps (web app and the mobile app) are in fact the 'same' application?
I want to avoid using the scope for full access to the user's Google Drive.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

Or is there another way that both apps can read/write the same folder?

Thanks in advance.

I also took a look at the [Google Picker API](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs) but it does not seem to be what I want.

Comment: if they are part of the same project on google cloud console i would expect them both to be able to read it.

Comment: They should be part of the same GCP project, that's the only way to "tell" the API. If they are not, you should use the `drive` scope instead.

Comment: You guys were right, how could I miss that. Thank you very much! Feel free to write your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this for documentation purposes.

As mentioned in comments, both apps should be part of the same [Google Cloud Platform project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects), that's the only way to "tell" the API that they are the same application.

If they are not part of the same project, you should use the `drive` scope instead.